# Why can Complex Forms be threaded at such high levels?

Tags: balance, shadowrun-sr5, spellcasting

There are a great many equivalencies between Resonance and Magic; many of their abilities are very similar both in fluff and mechanics. One difference that stands out is the limit at which their respective abilities can be used at.

### Spellcasting

> You must declare the Force at which to cast the spell... You can cast a spell at a Force up to **twice your Magic rating.** (emphasis mine)

### Threading

> When you thread a complex form, you choose a Level for the effect... You can choose a Level up to **three times your Resonance rating.** (again, emphasis mine)

I am well aware of the fact that the sourcebook is laden with typos and lazy editing. 
 **Is that all this is, a typo, does any published material explain the reason for this difference?**

Comment: If your real objection is that it seems unbalanced, you can ask about that, too:  "Is technomancy better than magic?  Q: Technomancers can thread at thrice Resonance while Magicians can summon/cast at merely twice Magic.  It would seem, then, since Magic and Resonance cost the same in terms of BP or Karma, that Resonance is simply superior.  Is that the case?"

Comment: Thanks Chan, that is more in line with what I'm looking for. And Wanderer, having played both I can assure you that higher level is not always a good thing, since that means higher fading as well. Pretty much any time you'd want a limit that high you're probably edging to break the limit anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Matrix isn't Meatworld. While mechanics might look similar at a glance, and while technomancers might be described as cyber-mages, the situation is not that simple.

A mage and a technomancer have a very important difference in capabilities. If a mage and a technomancer meet in a dark alley, the mage can blow up the technomancer's head. On the other hand, the wonder child of the digital age, the chosen of Resonance can brick the mage's commlink. If the mage has one. And if it's turned on.

Technomancer is bound to the Matrix. If something isn't networked, he can't affect it. On the other hand, mage isn't bound to the Astral, manabolt hurts a street sammy as much as it does a spirit. Those neat foci mage might get to pad his stats? Techies get none. It's not all in mage's favor, of course (for example, the concept of range as it works in spells does not apply in Matrix - mage needs to walk up to the enemy to cast Shatter on him, no such thing for a techie), but the point is - the advantages and disadvantages here are asymmetrical. If a mage is bad at something, it doesn't mean a technomancer will be bad at it. It also doesn't mean he will necessarily be good at it either. They are just different.

To sum it up - technomancers and mages fill different niches in the system, and direct numerical comparison between them is invalid.